# Join multiple logs through kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 2 types logs...

1. Http "GET" logs. Stores UUID, the raw HTTP request + total processing time. (Stored in "logs" topic, NOT keyed)
2. Event/Command log from the application. Stores UUID + the event generated of the request of 1 (Stored in "events" topic, has key)

What's the best way to join these guys? I know there are various platform to do this...

1. I was thinking first I need to to read the "logs" topic parse it and store it back into a "parsed" topic with the proper key.
2. Join "events" topic with the "parsed" topic.

Also events/commands (#2 logs) can come in days latter (but mostly instant within a minute or 2).

Comment: So I guess, I can create a json document in a ktable keep appending to it on the ktable and some point store the final document somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

What's the purpose of the join - is it to drive further processing, or for analytics?

Since you already have your data in Apache Kafka, I would recommend using  the [Kafka Streams API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/), and/or [KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-open-source-streaming-sql-for-apache-kafka/). KSQL runs on top of Kafka Streams. You can join between topics using either of these.

You can do things like rekey topics with KSQL as well.

Comment: Further processing. Have 1 document of all the logs and events together and some analytics.